# Generating a unique random number and storing it against user order - handling requests at same time?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the function below to generate a unique random number when customers complete an order in Woocommerce and saving it within an array so it can't be generated by another customer. I'm calling the function on the woocommerce_order_processing hook.

I'm just curious to know how bullet proof this solution is and how it would handle multiple customers ordering at the same time? Is it possible that they could end up with an identical number or will the database be able to return the array of numbers in use faster enough?

```
function add_lottery_ticket_number( $postId ) {
    if (metadata_exists('post', $postId, 'optionsToGive')) {
        $ticketOptions = get_post_meta( $postId, 'optionsToGive', true );
    } else {
        $lottery_max_tickets = get_post_meta( $postid, '_max_tickets', true );
        $ticketOptions = range(1, $lottery_max_tickets);
        shuffle($ticketOptions ); //random order of all number
    }
    $ticketAllocated = array_shift($ticketOptions); //take the first element
    update_post_meta( $postId, 'optionsToGive', $ticketOptions ); //update all the rest
    return $ticketAllocated;
}

for ( $i = 0; $i < $item_meta['_qty'][0]; $i++ ) {
    add_post_meta( $product_id, '_participant_id', $order->get_user_id() );
    $participants = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_lottery_participants_count', true ) ? get_post_meta( $product_id, '_lottery_participants_count', true ) : 0;
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_lottery_participants_count', intval( $participants ) + 1 );
    $this->add_lottery_to_user_metafield( $product_id, $order->get_user_id() );
    $ticketnumber = $this->add_lottery_ticket_number($product_id);
    $log_ids[] = $this->log_participant( $product_id, $order->get_user_id(), $ticketnumber, $order_id, $item );
}
```

**UPDATED**

I've created a table for all the ticket numbers to be stored into with a 'used' column like you suggested. I'm then using the $wpdb->query function within the foreach statement and am updating the table.

However, I'm unsure how i generate the random number to be used in WHERE ticket_number = $randomnumber' and for this to be unique so one customer ordering 5 tickets will have 5 different numbers. Does that make sense?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'ektgn_meta_to_line_item', 20, 4 );

function ektgn_meta_to_line_item( $order_id )
{

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $product_id = $item_product->get_product_id();
        $qty = get_field('maximum_entries', $product_id, true);
        $ticketOptions = range(1, $qty);
        $ticketAllocated = array_rand($ticketOptions, 1);

        $wpdb->query(
            "
            UPDATE wp_tickets 
            SET used = 1
            WHERE ticket_number= ".$ticketAllocated." AND lottery_id = ".$product_id." AND used = 0
            "
);     

}             

}
```

Comment: cant you just use an auto incremented database id?

Comment: It needs to be a randomly generated number from a value set in a meta field, max_tickets. Doesn't auto increment just go up by one each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair enough if you have only a couple of orders per day but amazon would definitely end up with multiple duplicate tickets this way. What you are looking for is an *atomic operation*.

Possible ways:

- Create a mysql table with a unique column for the ticket number. Since you can't insert a number twice... do { INSERT INTO tickets ($random_number) } while duplicate key error
- Create a mysql table with all tickets and a "used" flag column... do { UPDATE tickets SET used=1 WHERE ticket_number=$random_number and used=0; } while affected_rows == 0;
- Use a redis set... do { SADD tickets $random_number } while result == 0

Comment: Hi Sui, thanks for your answer. The ticket number is already within a table but I can't add it as a unique column because each product has a different value for the max_tickets set and the number is generated from this field. So it's possible that if you order two different products you will get the same number as the OptionsToGive will be relevant to each product. Does that make sense?

Comment: Creating a mysql table with all the tickets numbers would be tricky as i would need to create different tables for each product.

Comment: Are there any other ways i could split the tickets table so I don't have to create a table for each products tickets?

Comment: could you explain why the affected_rows == 0 does please?